# ¿como hacer que un Botón pueda agregar y actualizar?

Tags: visual-studio, botón

Tengo un proyecto en *Visual Studio* con una conexión en la base de datos *SQL Server*. Toda la información de mi base de datos se carga en un `DataGridView`. Por medio de un botón guardo los datos en mi tabla `dgv`, pero necesito que en el mismo botón de guardar también pueda actualizar los datos.

No se como hacer; tengo un método `guardar` y también tengo el método `actualizar` pero a la hora de llamarlo en `Button_click` no funciona. Le agradezco de antemano

```
 public bool guardarAgenda()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = conectarBD();
            cn.Open();
            String Consulta = "Insert into tblAgenda (identificacion,nombres,apellidos,direccion,telefono,profesion,email,fecha) values (@identificacion,@nombres,@apellidos,@direccion,@telefono,@profesion,@email,@fecha)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Consulta, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identificacion", txtIdentificacion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombres",txtNombres.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidos", txtApellidos.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", cmbProfesion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dtpFechaIngreso.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            mostraDatos(dgvTabla);

            txtIdentificacion.Clear();
            txtApellidos.Clear();
            txtNombres.Clear();
            txtTelefono.Clear();
            txtDireccion.Clear();
            txtemail.Clear();
            cmbProfesion.SelectedIndex = 0;
            dtpFechaIngreso.Value = DateTime.Now;
            return true;
        }
//actulizar
public bool modificar(String identificacion)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = conectarBD();
        cn.Open();
        String consulta = "UPDATE tblAgenda SET nombres=@nombres,apellidos=@apellidos,direccion=@direccion,telefono=@telefono,profesion=@profesion,email=@email,Fecha=@fecha  WHERE identificacion=@identificacion";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identificacion", identificacion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombres", txtNombres.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidos", txtApellidos.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", cmbProfesion.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dtpFechaIngreso.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        return true;

    }

    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            guardarAgenda();
            modificar(txtIdentificacion.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Ya lo depuraste pasa a paso, si te fijas cuando guardas la informacion en la base de datos terminas borrando los textbox y demas controles, y cuando pasas a la actualizacion, esos valores de los controles ya estan vacios.

Comment: También deberias de manejar algun flag para saber cuando vas a guardar y cuando actualizar, ya que piensas utilizar un mismo boton. Otra opcion seria que antes de guardar o actualizar consultes la identificación y con eso sabras si existe (actualizas), si no existe (creas y guardas)